# D3 - Disable grouping

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm building a line chart using D3 following [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245).  I have it working and it looks exactly as expected.

The problem I'm having is with the data.  When removing the sample data and using my own, everything is grouped together in a single point.

Example of my production data:

```
Date                | Close
01-01-2016 01:00:00 | 14.3
01-01-2016 01:00:00 | 13.2
01-01-2016 01:00:00 | 9.3
```

What I'm expecting to see based on the above are three points plotted in order.  What I'm getting is one point as it appears that D3 is grouping like dates.

My code is the exact same as what I've linked, except for the data.  How do I disable grouping to show the results as explained?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have all your data accumulated on one single date:

```
01-01-2016 01:00:00
```

Mike's data has this shape:

```
date    close
24-Apr-07   93.24     24
25-Apr-07   95.35     25
26-Apr-07   98.84     26
27-Apr-07   99.92     27
30-Apr-07   99.80     30
```

it's a time serie, see the diference?

If you want draw all data no matter if it's same date, must to use a simple line graph not a time graph.

From Mike's header page:

The chart employs conventional margins and a number of D3 features:

- d3.tsv - load and parse data
- **d3.time.format** - parse dates
- **d3.time.scale** - x-position encoding
- d3.scale.linear - y-position encoding
- d3.extent - compute domains
- d3.svg.axis - display axes
- d3.svg.line - display line shape